# Run Appiumtest on iOS Realdevice via. Intern

Tags: selenium, appium, intern

I’m currently trying to run my tests on an iOS iPhone7 PLUS.
The current situation is that I can trigger my testsuite from IntelliJ to the selenium HUB (Windows) and route the request to Appium Server (Mac). After that my WebDriverAgentRunner starts and open Safari on my iPhone unforunatley it starts appium.io instead of running my testsuite. Any Suggestions what could be the reason?

Below you can see the general informations and my AppiumServer Logfile.

I follow this guide to setup my WebDriverAgentRunner

https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md

Thank you in advance!!!

Best Regards

Kai

General:

Windows:

Windows 7
Running Selenium Hub (java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub)

Intern configuration:

```
tunnel: “NullTunnel”,
tunnelOptions: {
host: “localhost:4444”
// port: “4444”
},
```

environments: [ {
    browserName: "Safari",
    platformName: [ "iOS"],
    platformVersion: [ "10.3" ],
    platform: [ "MAC" ],
    deviceName: ["iPhone7Plus"],
    fixSessionCapabilities: "false"
}],
 proxyUrl: "http://XXXXX000:9000/",

Mac Book iOS 10.12.5 Sierra :
Appium Version 1.6.5
Running Appium Server (appium --nodeconfig iPhoneNode.json -U XXXX)

```
iPhoneNode.json
{
“capabilities”: [
{
“browserName”: “Safari”,
“maxInstance”: 1,
“platformName”: “iOS”,
“platformVersion” : “10.3”,
“startIWDP”: true,
“udid”: “UID_Pseudo”,
“deviceName”: “iPhone7Plus”,
“platform”: “MAC”
}
],
“configuration”:
{
“cleanUpCycle”:2000,
“timeout”:30000,
“proxy”: “org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy”,
“url”: “http://XXXXX:4723/wd/hub”,
“host”: “XXXXX”,
“port”: 4723,
“maxSession”: 1,
“register”: true,
“registerCycle”: 5000,
“hubPort”: 4444,
“hubHost”: “XXXXX000”,
“hub”: “XXXXX000:4444/grid/register”
}
}
```

I install the following packages on Mac:

```
npm install -g appium
npm install -g ios-deploy
npm install appium doctor
brew install libtoolize
brew install automaker
brew install --HEAD libmobiledevice
xcode-select–install
brew install carthage
```

Real Device
iPhone 7
Installed Apps
SafariLauncher & WebDriverAgentRunner via xCode

Now i try to start my envrioment:

Start SeleniumGrid Hub Sucessfully
Start AppiumServer and Connect to Hub Sucessfully

Start Test from IntelleJ getTimeout

Now the iPhone is Opening the Safari Browser and it navigate to the wrong wesbite (appium.io website)

For details see AppiumServerLog:

```
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{“name”:“build/webapp/app/intern”,“idle-timeout”:60,“browserName”:“Safari”,“platformName”:“iOS”,“platformVersion”:“10.3”,“platform”:“MAC”,“deviceName”:“iPhone7Plus”},null,null]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘newSessionRequested’ logged at 1500650988235 (17:29:48 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[Appium] Requested iOS support with version >= 10, using XCUITest driver instead of UIAutomation-based driver, since the latter is unsupported on iOS 10 and up.
[Appium] Creating new XCUITestDriver (v2.30.0) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium] name: ‘build/webapp/app/intern’
[Appium] idle-timeout: 60
[Appium] browserName: ‘Safari’
[Appium] platformName: ‘iOS’
[Appium] platformVersion: ‘10.3’
[Appium] platform: ‘MAC’
[Appium] deviceName: ‘iPhone7Plus’
[Appium] udid: ‘UID_Pseudo’
[debug] [XCUITest] XCUITestDriver version: 2.30.0
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by appium: name, idle-timeout, platform.
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: fa9234e0-c195-4384-9b29-8d437a76d215
[debug] [XCUITest] Xcode version set to ‘8.3.3’ (tools v8.3.2.0.1.1492020469)
[debug] [XCUITest] iOS SDK Version set to ‘10.3’
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘xcodeDetailsRetrieved’ logged at 1500650988431 (17:29:48 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Available devices: UID_Pseudo
[debug] [XCUITest] Creating iDevice object with udid ‘UID_Pseudo’
[XCUITest] Determining device to run tests on: udid: ‘UID_Pseudo’, real device: true
[XCUITest] Safari test requested
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘appConfigured’ logged at 1500650988600 (17:29:48 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘resetStarted’ logged at 1500650988600 (17:29:48 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Reset: running ios real device reset flow
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘resetComplete’ logged at 1500650988601 (17:29:48 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[debug] [iOSLog] Attempting iOS device log capture via libimobiledevice idevicesyslog
[debug] [iOSLog] Found idevicesyslog: ‘/usr/local/bin/idevicesyslog’
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘logCaptureStarted’ logged at 1500650988754 (17:29:48 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[XCUITest] Setting up real device
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘wdaStartAttempted’ logged at 1500650988757 (17:29:48 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[XCUITest] Using WDA path: ‘/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent’
[XCUITest] Using WDA agent: ‘/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj’
[XCUITest] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device
[debug] [XCUITest] Carthage found: ‘/usr/local/bin/carthage’
[debug] [XCUITest] Killing hanging processes
[debug] [XCUITest] Beginning test with command ‘xcodebuild build-for-testing test-without-building -project /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination id=UID_Pseudo -configuration Debug IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.3’ in directory ‘/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent’
[debug] [XCUITest] Output from xcodebuild will not be logged
[debug] [XCUITest] Starting iproxy to forward traffic from local port 8100 to device port 8100 over USB
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status - - ms - -
[debug] [XCUITest] Waiting up to 60000ms for WebDriverAgent to start
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [XCUITest] Log file for xcodebuild test: /Users/tnk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Logs/Test/BA8AABB7-9F1B-4C6F-9D63-BE4B3250C46E/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2017-07-21_172956-nNAexN.log
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status - - ms - -
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status - - ms - -
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status - - ms - -
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
ebug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘wdaSessionAttempted’ logged at 1500651032579 (17:30:32 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session. Retrying…
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘wdaSessionAttempted’ logged at 1500651033651 (17:30:33 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session. Retrying…
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status - - ms - -
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘wdaSessionAttempted’ logged at 1500651034660 (17:30:34 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session. Retrying…
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘wdaSessionAttempted’ logged at 1500651035670 (17:30:35 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session. Retrying…
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘wdaSessionAttempted’ logged at 1500651036680 (17:30:36 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session. Retrying…
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘wdaSessionAttempted’ logged at 1500651037690 (17:30:37 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session. Retrying…
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘wdaSessionAttempted’ logged at 1500651038751 (17:30:38 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session. Retrying…
^C[Appium] Received SIGINT - shutting down
[debug] [XCUITest] iproxy exited with code ‘null’
```

xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination ‘id=’ test

The test is running without an end see log:

```
2017-07-24 09:00:26.860964+0200 XCTRunner[259:9227] Running tests…
2017-07-24 09:00:27.495866+0200 XCTRunner[259:9227] Continuing to run tests in the background with task ID 1
Test Suite ‘All tests’ started at 2017-07-24 09:00:28.149
Test Suite ‘WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest’ started at 2017-07-24 09:00:28.150
Test Suite ‘UITestingUITests’ started at 2017-07-24 09:00:28.150
Test Case ‘-[UITestingUITests testRunner]’ started.
t = 0.00s Start Test at 2017-07-24 09:00:28.151
t = 0.00s Set Up
2017-07-24 09:00:28.162188+0200 XCTRunner[259:9347] [User Defaults] Failed to write value for key AutomationDisableFauxCollectionCells in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x17011f1d0> (Domain: com.apple.Accessibility, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null)): setting preferences outside an application’s container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access, switching to read-only
2017-07-24 09:00:28.162802+0200 XCTRunner[259:9227] Built at Jul 24 2017 07:59:00
2017-07-24 09:00:28.179892+0200 XCTRunner[259:9227] ServerURLHere->http://10.192.1.103:8100<-ServerURLHere
```